# Java version higher than 8 in Android unit test

Tags: android

As we all know, Android has a limited (depending on the API version) support for Java 8 features.
However, in my Android project, I have the unit test which are pure JVM code without platform dependencies. Can I use Java 9 or 10 in these unit tests?

If so, how do I set up them to use these Java versions?

Comment: you mean you have production code written in java 8 or lower and you want to write test code for that using java 9 or higher?

Comment: Yes, exactly this is my goal!

Comment: I don't see why that would not be possible, since unit tests (ran with junit) don't care about android. If necessary you can define a custom test configuration and specify JRE 1.9 to be used there